# Предупреждение в Google Play Console-ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ДЕЙСТВИЕ: автоматическая публикация в Google Play перестанет работать 1 декабря 2019 г

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-console, google-play-services

Всем доброго дня, недавно при публикации обновления приложения в Google Play Console появилось предупреждение:

> ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ДЕЙСТВИЕ: автоматическая публикация в Google Play перестанет работать 1 декабря 2019 г.
>   Ваше приложение использует старую версию Google Play Developer API. С 1 декабря 2019 г. поддержка версий 1 и 2 этого API прекратится, и вызовы этих версий не будут выполнены. Обновите его до версии 3 до этой даты.

Вот код в build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
       mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
       mavenCentral()

    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

и на уровне модуля приложения:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "test.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 22
        versionName '2.22'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

           minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

    }
}


dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev130-1.25.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Что вызывает это предупреждение? Что нужно добавить чтобы исчезло предупреждение?

Comment: Какое отношение Google Play API имеет к вашим исходникам Android приложения ?

Comment: Firebase Analytics, AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

Изменил в  в build.gradle: minSdkVersion с 16 на 19, опубликовал, предупреждение исчезло.